# What is the difference between var x=1 and x = 1 in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

This might be a dumb questions, but I'll ask it anyway. Is there a real difference between the 2 options that I should avoid using the latter when programming in Node.js?

Comment: The former creates a local variable, while the latter creates a global variable. If you use strict mode, only `var x = 1` would work.

Comment: If you are using 'use strict' in your js file then later one will give error. you cannot use undefined variable.Better use 'use strict' to avoid such circumsatnces.

Comment: @shreya, Thanks for your comment. But, what is use_strict, and how to use it?

Comment: just go through it http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'var x = 3' will create a variable within the current scope. Given this is declared in a function, x will not be available outside it, unless explicitly returned.

'x = 3' will create a variable within the global scope. Thus, any other code can access and alter its value. It's generally a bad practice to use variables in a global scope.

Comment: Thanks Rkn. What if I use something like this: var x=1,y=2,z=3; ... Does this mean only x is a local scope or all of the variables?

Comment: No, all x,y,z will get local scope..

Comment: Thanks, accepted the answer :)